# Proxy Switching on URL

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, socks, pac

I want to be able to set proxy rules on chrome so that when i go to a site defined in a rules file it will connect to it through the proxy. I have tried various extensions like Proxy SwichyOmega but it never seemed to work. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to automate this with selenium or is your question just not related to programming after all?

Comment: not programming, i need a proxy tool or something that can hook into chrome.

Comment: Sorry the crystal ball of my oracle is broken today.  So please give example for 2 URLs:  One which should be proxied and one which shall not.  Without it is difficult to understand what you want to archive or how it can be done with PAC file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think chrome supports this and I don't know any extension that can configure proxy. What I would do is to use a local proxy that can be configured that way. Privoxy for example can do it easily. So you point Chrome to use Privoxy and then you configure Privoxy to do the url specific routing.

Comment: Is it easy to configure a Host /Socks5, User+Pass and set URL rules with Privoxy?

Comment: I think it is reasonable easy. No GUI though. All in config files.